# Another incremental id for users' products

Tags: laravel

I have a `users` table and `products` table. Each user can have many products and everything goes fine with `id` in the products table.
What I am trying to do is to add another incremental column in relation to users.

I am trying to not only have:

user[1] could have product `id` [1,5,7] ❌
user[2] could have product `id` [2,3,4] ❌

But also:

user[1] has product `another_incrematal` [1,2,3,4,5, ....]  ✅ 
user[2] has product `another_incrematal` [1,2,3,4,5, ....]  ✅

Are there any built-in methods in laravel that could do so?

Thanks in advance.

```
// User
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

// Product
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have for your relationships?

Comment: No need to add `[laravel]` in the title; tagging it with `laravel` does that automatically.

Comment: Also, don't post code in the comments; please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73804621/edit) and add it there (I have done this for you this time).

Comment: Lastly, if you want User to have many Products, but each Product can belong to many Users, then you need a `many-to-many`, not a `one-to-many` (which is what you currently have). Please read the documentation on how to set that up: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: No, I am not willing to have a `many-to-many` relationship. Imagine that User A is inserting products that took id of [1,2,3] so if another User B for example comes to insert products they will take ids of [4,5,6]. 

How can I give User B products incremental col starts with 1, not with 4 as in `id`. @Tim

Comment: Ah I see; I misunderstood the numbering; thought those we're `id`s. I kinda get what you're trying to do, but I'm sure you know that you can't have multiple `products` rows with the same `id`. Essentially "Product #1" for User A should be different than "Product #1" for User B. To my knowledge, there isn't anything built-in to handle that; you'll need to count the products and increment when you add a new one, like `'products_index' => count($user->products) + 1`, but that doesn't handle deleted products, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to introduce an intermediate model to represent the relationship between a `User` and `Product` - `UserProduct` (or something better depending on your use-case) which has `user_id`, `product_id` and a third field of, say, `index`. A `User hasMany UserProducts` and a `Product hasOne UserProduct` As @TimLewis pointed out, you would have to generate `index` at the time of insertion by counting the products for a user and adding one.

```
//User
public function products() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, UserProduct::class)
}

//many ways to do this but one example is...
public function addProduct($product) {

    UserProduct::create([
        'user_id' => $this->id,
        'product_id' => $product_id
        'index' => $this->products()->count() + 1
    ]);

}

//Product
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, UserProduct::class)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zakalwe.
Will `$this->products()->count() + 1` be another sql query?

Comment: Yes. Built through the relationship `products`